# Cannot connect to Google Cloud MySQL using SSL with PDO on Google Compute

Tags: mysql, ssl, pdo, google-compute-engine

Just figured this out and wanted to share.

I am able to connect to MySQL using SSL with the PHP PDO from my local machine. The same code fails when run from a Google Compute Engine instance. I know the certs and IP address are setup correctly because connecting via the MySQL command line client using SSL on the instance works perfectly.

**MySQL command line works on Compute:**

mysql --ssl-ca=server-ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem \
             --host=111.111.111.111 --user=someuser --password

**PHP PDO does not work on Compute:**

```
<?php
new PDO ('mysql:host=111.111.111.111;port=3306;dbname=mydatabase', 
          'someuser', 
          'somepassword,
          array(
             PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => '/somedir/ssl/client-key.pem',
             PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/somedir/ssl/client-cert.pem',
             PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/somedir/ssl/ca-cert.pem'
            )
        );
```

PDO gives this error on Compute:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2026] SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation'

Answer (score 0):

Remove the CA cert from the PDO connection. 
Remove this key/value from the array:

PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/somedir/ssl/ca-cert.pem'

Like so:

```
<?php
new PDO ('mysql:host=111.111.111.111;port=3306;dbname=mydatabase', 
          'someuser', 
          'somepassword,
          array(
             PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => '/somedir/ssl/client-key.pem',
             PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/somedir/ssl/client-cert.pem'
            )
        );
```

PDO with SSL will silently fail back to an insecure connection under certain conditions. To test that SSL is working run this query on the connection:

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';
```

It should return something like:

```
 Ssl_cipher => DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

Otherwise the it will return an empty value.

Comment: Not working at all. server_ca is a requirement for Cloud SQL over SSL. So that openssl error comes: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.

Comment: @lazycommit, forgot I posted this, yes you are correct. PHP just does not throw an error.  The best way I have found, assuming you are using the second generation sql service is to use the mysql proxy. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy . It make it easier for dev as well.

Comment: thank you. familiar with it. not an option for us because of apps in one project isolation scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more PDO attribute (as per comments by Desislav Kamenov in http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) into your array so that your PDO becomes ...

```
new PDO ('mysql:host=111.111.111.111;port=3306;dbname=mydatabase',
      'someuser',
      'somepassword',
      array(
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => '/somedir/ssl/client-key.pem',
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/somedir/ssl/client-cert.pem',
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/somedir/ssl/ca-cert.pem',
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false
      )
    );
```